# Copy rows from one Datatable to another DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable

How can I copy specific rows from DataTable to another Datable in c#? There will be more than one row.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable1.Rows) {
    if (/* some condition */)
        dataTable2.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
}
```

The above example assumes that `dataTable1` and `dataTable2` have the same number, type and order of columns.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in "This row already belongs to
another table."

Comment: @McArthey No, it wouldn't; a new row is being created from the values in the existing row. The row itself is not being added to the other DataTable.

Comment: This is resulting in "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table".

Comment: @Vinod If that's the case, then your two tables have a different number of columns. I stated clearly in my answer that this method only works when the two tables have the same number, type and order of columns.

Comment: @BradleySmith it gives me this exception . "This row already belongs to another table."

Comment: @DawoodAbbasi That would only happen if you left out the `ItemArray` part at the end of the expression. Make sure you are adding the row's values, not the row itself.

Comment: @BradleySmith now it gives me this exception "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Comment: @DawoodAbbasi As I said in my original answer, "dataTable1 and dataTable2 have the same number, type and order of columns". If you're getting that exception then the tables must not have the same number of columns.

Comment: @BradleySmith how to give same columns to the new DataTable?? How to Create the second DataTable??

Comment: @DawoodAbbasi Refer to the MSDN documentation for the `DataTable.Clone` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx

Comment: Though your answer technically is correct, your code sample doesn't address your assumptions. The answer by @RageeshGr handles all the assumptions and IMHO is written more concisely and is less error prone.

Comment: First you need to populate the other table with columns. Otherwise it will give error. "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table"

Comment: @Ravi, so what is the alternative if this solution causes decrease in performance?

Comment: This proved a useful solution to me to copy all of the contents of one datatable into another datatable which already contained data.

Comment: The Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray) was the fastest by a bit more than ImportRow
 in a 5000 iteration test with a strongly typed DataTable<T>. 
 Total size of the source datatable  was 675 rows.  I am building picklist data sources with this.
LOAD CACHE: 0:0.10.367
LINQ QRY CACHE: 0:0.0.0


Iterations: 5000

COPYTO w/ MERGE AVG (ms): 12.07034856
MERGE NO TEMP TABLE AVG (ms): 16.70951208
FOREACH ADD Rows.Add(r.ItemArray) AVG (ms): 11.6610181
FOREACH ImportRow(r) AVG (ms): 11.81321906

Comment: Here is one of the tests....
beginTime = DateTime.Now;
 picklistDt.Clear();
 foreach (ParamtrDtRow r in qry.AsEnumerable())
  picklistDt.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray);
 endTime = DateTime.Now;
 diff = endTime.Subtract(beginTime);
 diffForEachAddRowSum += diff;
 res = String.Format("{0}: {1}:{2}.{3}.{4}", "FOREACH Rows.Add(r.ItemArray)", diff.Hours, diff.Minutes, diff.Seconds, diff.Milliseconds);

Answer (score 124):

Copy Specified Rows from  Table to another

```
// here dttablenew is a new Table  and dttableOld is table Which having the data 

dttableNew  = dttableOld.Clone();  

foreach (DataRow drtableOld in dttableOld.Rows)
{
   if (/*put some Condition */)
   {
      dtTableNew.ImportRow(drtableOld);
   }
}
```

Comment: If I am no longer need to use dttableOld after import, do I still need to use Clone()?

Comment: @Sam regarding your question, Clone is to copy the table structure, if your table is already the same data-type, then you don't need it.

Comment: There is better way to do this.   entityColumnMetadata = changedColumnMetadata.AsEnumerable().Where(dataRow => entityName.Equals(dataRow["EntityName"])).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: +1 Good answer. Worth pointing out that `DataTable::ImportRow` is more tolerant, compared with `DataTable::Rows::Add(...)`, when it comes to the number and order of columns . If a column is missing in the imported row, the value is set to NULL.

Answer (score 23):

Try This

```
    String matchString="ID0001"//assuming we have to find rows having key=ID0001
    DataTable dtTarget = new DataTable();
    dtTarget = dtSource.Clone();
    DataRow[] rowsToCopy;
    rowsToCopy = dtSource.Select("key='" + matchString + "'");
    foreach (DataRow temp in rowsToCopy)
    {
        dtTarget.ImportRow(temp);
    }
```

Comment: @ManojSavalia, so what is the alternative that doesn't cost performance?

Answer (score 22):

Check this out, you may like it (previously, please, clone table1 to table2):

```
table1.AsEnumerable().Take(recodCount).CopyToDataTable(table2,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Or:

```
table1.AsEnumerable().Where ( yourcondition  ) .CopyToDataTable(table2,LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Comment: This is a much better approach because it uses built-in capability to range-copy or even select rows from one DataTable to another without explicitly iterating through each, unlike all of the foreach loop, .ForEach method based answers.

Answer (score 16):

Supported in: 4, 3.5 SP1, you can now just call a method on the object.

```
DataTable dataTable2 = dataTable1.Copy()
```

Comment: Technically this creates a copy of a datatable.  While it's not explicitly stated in the question, it's possible that dataTable2 already exists and has other rows in it which we don't want to lose.  Also, the question specifically states "specific rows", whereas this only handles all rows.

Answer (score 7):

As a result of the other posts, this is the shortest I could get:

```
DataTable destTable = sourceTable.Clone();
sourceTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => /* condition */ ).ToList().ForEach(row => destTable.ImportRow(row));
```

Comment: Which is basically a foreach. Also, you're not filtering through a condition, as requested by the OP.

Comment: Now if I clear out the `sourceTable` will the `destTable` also clear?

Comment: I want to be able to assign a value and clear out the original variable without clearing out the destination.

Answer (score 6):

I've created an easy way to do this issue

```
 DataTable newTable = oldtable.Clone();    
 for (int i = 0; i < oldtable.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
   DataRow drNew = newTable.NewRow();    
   drNew.ItemArray = oldtable.Rows[i].ItemArray;    
   newTable.Rows.Add(drNew);   
 }
```

Comment: An even easier way to do this is instead of using a `for`, use a `foreach (Datarow dr...)`

Answer (score 3):

I needed to copy rows from multiple tables with the same structure into a new table to be used as a datasource for datagridview:

```
// Generate DataTable[] alltables from multiple datatables

DataTable newTable = alltables[0].Clone();
foreach (DataTable dt in alltables)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
      newTable.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

below sample would be the fastest way to copy one row.
each cell is being copied based on the column name.
in case you dont need a specific cell to copy then have a try catch or add if.
if your going to copy more than 1 row then loop the code below.

```
DataRow dr = dataset1.Tables[0].NewRow();
for (int i = 0; i < dataset1.Tables[1].Columns.Count; i++)
{
    dr[dataset1.Tables[1].Columns[i].ColumnName] = dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[0][i];
}

datasetReport.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
```

dataset1.Tables[1].Rows[**0**][i]; change the index 0 to your specified row index or you can use a variable if your going to loop or if its going to be logical

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void CopyDataTable(DataTable table){
     // Create an object variable for the copy.
     DataTable copyDataTable;
     copyDataTable = table.Copy();
     // Insert code to work with the copy.
 }
```

Comment: your code works perfect to me, is a very simple code ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

To copy whole datatable just do this:

```
DataGridView sourceGrid = this.dataGridView1;
DataGridView targetGrid = this.dataGridView2;
targetGrid.DataSource = sourceGrid.DataSource;
```

Comment: the question is on how to copy specific rows from a data table, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want single command SQL query for that:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE002 
(COL001_MEM_ID, COL002_MEM_NAME, COL002_MEM_ADD, COL002_CREATE_USER_C, COL002_CREATE_S)
SELECT COL001_MEM_ID, COL001_MEM_NAME, COL001_MEM_ADD, COL001_CREATE_USER_C, COL001_CREATE_S
FROM TABLE001;
```

This query will copy data from `TABLE001` to `TABLE002` and we assume that both columns had different column names.

Column names are mapped one-to-one like:

COL001_MEM_ID -> COL001_MEM_ID

COL001_MEM_NAME -> COL002_MEM_NAME

COL001_MEM_ADD -> COL002_MEM_ADD

COL001_CREATE_USER_C -> COL002_CREATE_USER_C

COL002_CREATE_S -> COL002_CREATE_S

You can also specify where clause, if you need some condition.

Answer (score 0):

There is better way to do this.

DataTable targetDataTable = new DataTable();
targetDataTable = changedColumnMetadata.AsEnumerable().Where(dataRow => entityName.Equals(dataRow["EntityName"])).CopyToDataTable();

Please try this and let me know in case of any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it calling the [DataTable.Copy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataTable_Copy) method, for example:

```
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
   dt = _BOSearchView.DS.Tables[BusLib.TPV.TableName.SearchView].Copy();
   ds.Tables.Add(dt);
   UltGrdSaleExcel.SetDataBinding(ds, dt.TableName, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use Merge, this will append all rows of newDataTable with oldDateTale

```
oldDateTale.Merge(newDataTable);
```