# Why is DataTable copy getting truncated when the original is being truncated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am trying to preserve a copy of the original DataTable while trying to truncate the original for another purpose.  But when i truncate the original, the copy also gets truncated.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, conn))
{
    //Set Time to minute and a half, should not take longer than that!
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 90;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable copyDt = new DataTable();

    //Check the state of the database connection. If closed, then open it.
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Open();

    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    copyDt = dt.Copy();

    if (Session["ServiceRequestSearch"] != null)
    {
        ((DataTable)Session["ServiceRequestSearch"]).Clear();
        ((DataTable)Session["ServiceRequestSearch"]).Dispose();
        Session.Remove("ServiceRequestSearch");
    }

    Session["ServiceRequestSearch"] = copyDt;

    if (dt.Rows.Count > take)
        for (int i = take; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            dt.Rows[i].Delete();

    dt.AcceptChanges();
    TextBox.Text = dt.Rows.Count + "";
    TextBox2.Text = ((DataTable)Session["ServiceRequestSearch"]).Rows.Count + "";



    //Close SQL data connection if it is still open.
    if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Close();
}
```

They both show the same number for the row count, even though the copy should be a lot higher.

Comment: Are you certain that rows are being deleted from the original DataTable?

Comment: If you are only trying to delete rows from the in-memory DataTable, and not from the underlying database, you might see what happens when you use Remove() instead of Delete().

You could also try out some Linq code like foreach (var row in Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(take)) { row.Remove(); }

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where or what you are setting `take` to, but right before your loop, you are checking if your row count is greater than `take` and then setting `i = take` in your for loop. If `take` is the same number as your row count, you will not have deleted any rows.

That looks like your culprit and I advise you step through your code and verify your `dt.Rows[i].Delete();` triggers a breakpoint.

Your check for if `dt.Rows.Count > take` seems a little redundant too. Your for loop will already limit the correct number of rows that need to be deleted. Depending on what `take` is set to, it may be failing that check.

**EDIT:**
Actually looking at your code some more, I think I realized the mistake you made

You want something like this instead:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > take)
    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i > take; i--)
        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
```

Not exactly sure if take is supposed to just delete the first items or not, but hopefully that will get you on the right track for being able to delete your rows.

**EDIT 2:**
I have updated the for loop after it was caught that items should be removed in reverse. Thanks @YuriyGalanter.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `copyDt` is getting truncated

Comment: @YuriyGalanter True. However, there is no evidence that any actual rows are being deleted at all. If he comes back saying that there were originally X rows in both tables and at the end there were Y rows, I will go ahead and delete the answer. There isn't much information to really go off of and looking at MSDN, Copy() sounds like changes made to the original or copy should not affect the other.

Comment: I stand corrected. I was thrown off by "should have more rows" and didn't account for the fact that maybe no deletion is taking place. Btw, I'd start deleting from the highest row index going by `i--`, otherwise there *might be no higher rows to delete* after lower ones already deleted

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Good point. I didn't even think about that. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with the below code.
Was getting an exception no row at index after deleting records from original data table, just because it removes the rows from the table and counter will go to the number of rows as the orinigal table had, so you need to implement some algorithm to control the counter length of the loop at the time of deleting records from data table, it wont be effecting the copy version.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtCopy = new DataTable();


    dt.Columns.Add("Test1");
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = counter.ToString();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }


    dtCopy = dt.Copy();

    int counterLength = 10;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < counterLength; counter++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[counter][0]) > 6)
        {
            dt.Rows[counter].Delete();
            counterLength--;
        }
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copying each value like

```
copyDt = dt.Clone();
foreach(DataRows row in dt.Rows)
{
    copyDt.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
}
```

[copy-rows-from-datatable-to-another-datatable-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-datatable-to-another-datatable-c-sharp)