# Copy specific columns from one DataTable to another

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Have some read in data (from excel file) in a DataTable and now I want to filter this and copy only specific columns to the other one!

dataTable format:

```
some data 
ColA|ColB|ColC
xxxx|xxxx|xxxx
some data
```

`some data` represents other table data not related to ColA-ColC

How can I copy ColA-ColC with xxxx to the new DataTable?

Thx

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Copy the whole table and remove the columns you don't want.

```
DataTable copyDataTable;
copyDataTable = table.Copy();
copyDataTable.Columns.Remove("ColB");
```

or

```
int columnIndex = 1;//this will remove the second column
DataTable copyDataTable;
copyDataTable = table.Copy();
copyDataTable.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

Comment: I used this to copy the columns only by adding a ".clear()" statement after doing the copy().

Comment: What if we have a large set of columns. It would be a hassle to remove them one by one. Isn't there a way to just copy the column we need?

Comment: @RamiZebian you should probably check out the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18402444/2401981

Comment: A gotcha is that calculated columns need to be removed after the columns that the calculation uses.

Comment: Using remove or removeAt is suitable when you have few columns but not when you have many columns and you only want a few. So how to do the opposite, I mean, to only select a few columns you want?

Comment: @Ralph maybe you want to check Arshad's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18402444/2401981

Answer (score 52):

You can simply do it by using [DataView.ToTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8ycds2f.aspx) :

```
System.Data.DataView view = new System.Data.DataView(yourOriginalTable);
System.Data.DataTable selected = 
        view.ToTable("Selected", false, "col1", "col2", "col6", "col7", "col3");
```

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Column 'xxx' does not belong to underlying table

Comment: It means `xxx` column is not present in your `DataTable`.

Comment: I think the problem is that I have this other data (some data) in header of DataTable and the desired columns are below. Column xxx is definitely in table!

Comment: i think this one is the good answer out of these,but unfortunately the guy ticked other.Any way nice approach Arshad

Comment: this does not work for me and I don't know how to fix the problem

Answer (score 3):

please check this

```
  foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable1.Rows) {
    if (/* some condition */)
        dataTable2.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
     }
```

The above example assumes that both table have the same number, type and order of columns.

here is the actual [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-datatable-to-another-datatable-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Define your copy DataTable with only the interest columns. You can loop on columns of source row and set the value to the target row with this sample code :

```
public void IntegrateRow(DataRow p_RowCible, DataRow p_RowSource)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (DataColumn v_Column in p_RowCible.Table.Columns)
                {
                    string ColumnName = v_Column.ColumnName;
                    if (p_RowSource.Table.Columns.Contains(ColumnName))
                    {
                        p_RowCible[ColumnName] = p_RowSource[ColumnName];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using LINQ

Assume we have two `DataTable`. 1. `dtSource` and 2. `dtDestination`.

if `dtDestination` has no rows then use below code to generate blank rows.

```
dtSource.AsEnumerable().All(row => { dtDestination.Rows.Add(); return true; });
```

Below code will copy particular `DataColumn` data to `DataColumn` of another `DataTable`. Assume both Tables have same number of rows.

```
int rowIdx = 0;
dtDestination.AsEnumerable().All(row => { row["colName"] = dtSource.Rows[rowIdx++]["colName"]; return true; });
```

Answer (score 0):

This method receives a data table (TextFileTable) as a parameter and proceeds to copy the selected contents of TextFileTable into tblFormat table.In the add row statement the number of columns, must match the number of columns in the target ted table,even though the the two table can be of different sizes.

```
public DataTable CopyTable (DataTable TextFileTable)
        {
            DataTable tblFormat = new DataTable();

                tblFormat.Columns.Add("ColumnA");
                tblFormat.Columns.Add("ColumnB");
                tblFormat.Columns.Add("ColumnC");
                tblFormat.Columns.Add("ColumnD");
                tblFormat.Columns.Add("ColumnE");

                for (int i = 0; i < TextFileTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    tblFormat.Rows.Add(new string[] { TextFileTable.Rows[i][0].ToString(), TextFileTable.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    TextFileTable.Rows[i][2].ToString(), TextFileTable.Rows[i][8].ToString(), TextFileTable.Rows[i][9].ToString() });

                }


            return tblFormat;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same fix in vb.net

Dim view As DataView = New DataView(TB)
Dim selected As DataTable = view.ToTable("Selected", False, "id", "col1", "col2")