# copy only the first column with data from one DataTable to another new DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net

My `DataTable` has many columns more than 35 columns. Among them I want to copy the first column "SYMBOL_QA" data to another new `DataTable`.

I searched in internet but did not found any suitable approaches. One approach I found was to copy the whole `DataTable` as it is, then delete the unwanted columns. But I have 35 columns and deleting all of them one by one will not be good approach.

```
protected void SendDataTable(DataTable dSource)
{
    DataTable dTarget = new DataTable();
    dTarget.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SYMBOL_QA_"));
    int rowIdx = 0;
    dTarget.AsEnumerable().All(row => { row["SYMBOL_QA_"] = dSource.Rows[rowIdx++]["SYMBOL_QA"]; return true; });

}
```

This code block is not working. How can I do this ?

Comment: If you only want one column why not convert to a list<T> of the data type? What is the purpose of creating another datatable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy specific columns from one DataTable to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402324/copy-specific-columns-from-one-datatable-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected DataTable CopyColumn(DataTable sourceTable, string columnName)
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(columnName));

    foreach(DataRow sourceRow in sourceTable.Rows)
    {
         var destRow = result.NewRow();
         destRow[columnName] = sourceRow[columnName];
         result.Rows.Add(destRow);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that the easiest method to do what you have requested is through the [DataView.ToTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.totable?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_DataView_ToTable_System_Boolean_System_String___) method

```
DataTable dTarget = dSource.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "SYMBOL_QA");
```

It is just a single line and it

> Creates and returns a new DataTable based on rows in an existing
>   DataView.