# Add range rows from one DataTable to another

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Have a DataTable and I need to create another one having a subset range of rows from the first. So I want the second DataTable to have row n till n + y from the first one. How can I do this please?

```
DataTable limitData = new DataTable();
for (int rowIndex = startingRow; rowIndex < endingRow; rowIndex++)
{
    limitData.Rows.Add(columnarData.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray);
}
```

gives an error: "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

The code is in C# .NET 4.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-datatable-to-another-datatable-c-sharp

Comment: gives an error!!! why don't you post error details then?

Comment: Sorry, got disconnected before I could complete typing. Network issues. Added error message.

Comment: It is because you limitData has new columns, what you did is just declare then you havent define the columns equal to columnarData coumns

Comment: @Jade, how do I do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this** and let me hear from if this works

```
DataTable limitData =limitData.Clone();
for (int rowIndex = startingRow; rowIndex < endingRow; rowIndex++)
{
    limitData.Rows.Add(columnarData.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray);
}
```

or

```
DataTable limitData =limitData.Clone();
foreach (DataRow dr in columnarData.Rows)
{
    limitData.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works now. But is it better to use Rows.Add(columnarData.ImportRow([rowIndex]) ? as suggested by @geek

Comment: i don't know the performance but it may also serves the same purpose.  See also my updates I added a new option and there might be other simplier solutions out there.

Comment: No Need to make for loop to transfer data , you just need to put SourceDT=DestinationDT.Copy();

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
    {
       if(some condition))
       {
          extractedData.ImportRow(r);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can I use and index into the dt. There is no if condition to restrict to. I need a subset of rows.

Comment: If I use ImportRow in my code, it adds the rows but there are no columns!

Answer (score 0):

`Union()` also work:

```
dt1 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Union(dt2.AsEnumerable()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Reference from [this post](https://forums.asp.net/t/1692251.aspx?Adding+multiple+rows+to+a+datatable).