# Error while Using datatable.Rows.Add(dRow)

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I have a datatable in which some rows needed to be copied to a new datatable on some condition.My statements are as below.

```
dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
DataRow[] dRows = dt1.Select("IS_ALLOWED=" + false);
for (int i = 0; i < dRows.Length; i++)
{
   dtPerm.Rows.Add(dRows[i]);  //------(1)   
   //dtPerm.ImportRow(dRows[i]);  //------(2)   
}
```

But while debugging from ------(1). It jumps to catch. The exception is

```
"This row already belongs to another table."
```

The ----(2) doesn't making any error and the Rows are not adding,But the row is empty and only have a single column.

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4020284/1134076

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy rows from Datatable to another Datatable c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-datatable-to-another-datatable-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `for` loop to something like this :

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dRows)
   {
       dtPerm.ImportRow(row);
   }
```

And before adding the rows to the `DataTable`, make sure you have made the columns to store the row values. See this code :

```
 DataTable dtPerm = new DataTable();
 dtPerm.Columns.Add("Column1");
 dtPerm.Columns.Add("Column2");
 dtPerm.Columns.Add("Column3");
 dtPerm.Columns.Add("Column4");
 dtPerm.Columns.Add("Column5");
```

After this, place the above shown `for` loop and this will work just fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.. I think it is possible to use 
dtTarget=dtSource.Clone() instead of the statements you added

Comment: Probably. I added them just in case if you forgot to do that and because of it you received that error. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I added a statement above the loop starts and modified the code inside the loop and it is working fine now

```
dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
dtPerm = dt1.Clone();
DataRow[] dRows = dt1.Select("IS_ALLOWED=" + false);
for (int i = 0; i < dRows.Length; i++)
{
   dtPerm.ImportRow(dRows[i]);  //------(2)   
}
```