# Foreach row in datatable1 store in datatable2

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarow

I am trying to do a foreach loop that stores each row from datatable1 into datatable2, so foreach row in datatable1 store the row in datatable2, this is what I have so far:

```
public static DataTable datatable2 = new DataTable();

public void createDatatable()
{
    profile p = new profile();
    DataTable datatable1 = p.getResults(System.Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"]));

    foreach (DataRow dr in datatable1.Rows)
    {
        datatable2 = datatable1.Copy();
    }
}
```

This just copies the columns too which I don't want, I just want each row stored from datatable2 into datatable1

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy rows from Datatable to another Datatable c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-datatable-to-another-datatable-c-sharp)

Comment: FYI, DataTable.Copy does not need to gon in that loop. The loop is actually just Copying the entire Datatable over and over.

Comment: @brendan That does not work, the foreach loop displays it multiple times according to how many rows you have. I have 3 rows, and now my datatable has 3x of the same rows because of the foreach

Answer (score 0):

I assume dataTable1 & dataTable2 has same schema (same number of columns with similar datatype). Don't use `.Copy()`. Use `Rows.Add` to copy content as follows,

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable1.Rows) {
        dataTable2.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
}
```