# how to copy a row of a dataset into another dataset?

Tags: c#

i am looping through a dataset with 2 loops trying to find the rows which have have their ID matched with the assigned value to an array and if they matched i would like to copy that row into another table. for example:

```
DataSet dsWinners = new DataSet();
for(int i =0;i<=TotalWinners;i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        //this is my ds table 0
        left = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"]);
        //this is my array 
        right = Convert.ToInt16(Winners[i, 0]);

        if ( left == right )//if array value matechs with ds.table[0] ID
        {
            dsWinners.Tables[0].Rows[i] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j];
        }
    }
}
```

how can i get record/row And copy it into a new table and if i cant copy that row like this, is there an alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    DataTable tempDt = new DataTable();
    tempDt = ds.Tables[0].Clone();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        int rowIndex = ds.Tables[0].Rows.IndexOf(x);
        if (rowIndex < TotalWinners && 
            Convert.ToInt16(x["ID"]) == Convert.ToInt16(Winners[rowIndex, 0]))
        {
            tempDt.ImportRow(x);
        }
    });
    DataSet dsWinners = new DataSet();
    dsWinners.Tables.Add(tempDt);
```

EDIT:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> winnersList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalWinners; i++)
    {
        winnersList.Add(Winners[i, 0], Winners[i, 1]);
    }
    string idList = string.Join("','", winnersList.Select(x => x.Key));
    DataSet dsWinners = new DataSet();
    dsWinners.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[0].Select("ID IN ('" + idList + "')").CopyToDataTable());
    dsWinners.Tables[0].Columns.Add("prize_amt", typeof(string));
    dsWinners.Tables[0].Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        x["prize_amt"] = winnersList[x["ID"].ToString()];
    });
    dsWinners.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: @Ali How about this?

Comment: i get "Index was outside the bounds of the array." on if line !!!

Comment: @Ali How about this edited one? Now its assumed that `TotalWinners` is the number of elements in your array

Comment: its working but the result im getting is wrong. im only getting 1 row !

Comment: and sometimes i get none actually!

Comment: @Ali Could you please try my edited answer...

Comment: its getting result but the result are not the ones coming from the array!!!

Comment: What is the type of `ID` field in `ds.Tables[0]` table?

Comment: its string but i convert it to int everytime. i had to get it string bcoz the array is a 2D array. the first part is a random ID and the second part is the category which is string.

Comment: oh i just found that i actually gives the right result ...just that it gives it in a random sort. THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: just a quick question if you dont mind me asking, if i want to add the second part of the array to dsWinners,  how would i be able to do that?

Comment: Second part of the 2D array is a string field right? and also what is the name of the corresponding field in `ds.Tables[0]`?

Comment: that is not included in the ds! all of the numbers in first part of the array were random numbers, and second part is the prize they won. so i just want to add that to the table as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80018/discussion-between-ali-and-vanest).

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet dsWinners = new DataSet();
DataTable dataTable= ds.Tables[0].Clone();

for(int i =0;i<=TotalWinners;i++)
  {
       for (int j = 1; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
       {
          //this is my ds table 0
          left = Convert.ToInt16(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"]);
          //this is my array 
          right = Convert.ToInt16(Winners[i, 0]);

          if ( left == right )//if array value matechs with ds.table[0] ID
          {
            //  dsWinners.Tables[0].Rows[i] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[j];
              dataTable.Rows.Add( ds.Tables[0].Rows[j]);
           }
      }
  }
dsWinners.Add(dataTable);
```

Comment: after solving that i get the following error :This row already belongs to another table.

Comment: change the last line to  dsWinners.Tables.Add(dataTable);

Comment: dataTable.Rows.Add( ds.Tables[0].Rows[j].ItemArray); // it will fix your problem, [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-datatable-to-another-datatable-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dt = new DataTable("ExampleTable");
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age",typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Age"] = 30;
dr["Name"] = "Mike";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: my datacolumn varies each time ... i cant add them manually

Answer (score 0):

If i read your question right then you need to copy rows from one dataset when certain condition is met and transfer it to other one.Assuming that both the dataset have same structure this example should suffice.

```
      DataSet DSResult = new DataSet();
        DSResult.Tables.Add();

        DSResult.Tables[0].Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        DSResult.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));

        DSResult.Tables[0].Rows.Add(1,"Jon");
        DSResult.Tables[0].Rows.Add(2, "Kyle");
        DSResult.Tables[0].Rows.Add(3, "Sam");
        DSResult.Tables[0].Rows.Add(4, "Peter");
        DSResult.Tables[0].Rows.Add(5, "Lily");


        DataSet DSWinners = new DataSet();
        DSWinners.Tables.Add();
        DSWinners = DSResult.Clone();

        int[] Id = new int[] { 1, 4, 5 }; //condition to match

        foreach (int val in Id)
        {
            DataRow[] Samplerow =
              DSResult.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
             .Where(item => item.row.Field<int>("ID") == val)
             .Select(item => item.row)
             .ToArray();
                DSWinners.Tables[0].ImportRow(Samplerow[0]);

            // If both tables are not same then
               string YourVal=Samplerow[0]["ID"].ToString();
                DSWinners.Tables[0].Rows.Add();
                DSWinners.Tables[0].Rows[0]["YourColumnname"]=Yourval //Should have same Datataype


        }
```

Comment: you got me right. but there is a problem. both dataset dont have the same structure since one the data is filled in with all data and the second one is a new dataset

Comment: my datacolumn varies each time ... i cant add them manually