# How copy MS SQL table data to another same table in SQL

Tags: c#, sql

What is the way to copy MS SQL server table tdata to the same structural table in MS SQL server from C# application

Comment: This answer was useful for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-one-datatable-to-another-datatable

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas no its about DataTable, This about MS SQL database table

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
insert into [TargetTable] from select * from [SourceTable]
```