# c# How to Copy a row from one DataTable and Insert it in other at a specific position

Tags: c#, winforms

Implementation of methodology which looks similar to this
       `DataTable1.Rows.InsertAt(DataTable2.Rows[0], position);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy rows from one Datatable to another DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020270/copy-rows-from-one-datatable-to-another-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

The method is just simple as

```
       `DataRow DataRow2 = DataTable2.NewRow();
        DataRow2.ItemArray = DataTable1.Rows[_oneIndex].ItemArray;
        DataTable2.Rows.InsertAt(DataRow2, position);`
```